# Run a condition after each click function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this `jquery` code for a multilevel `dropdown`. Everything works just perfectly.

I just want to change the color of the text of the list that is active and back to normal when inactive.

Every time I put an if statement inside the function, it runs with the click function and not after the function has been executed.

Hence my `if statement` doesn't give the desired output.

Is there a way to put a condition and execute it every time after the clicking has happened?

```
$('.navbar-nav>li').on("click", function(event) {
    //debugger;

    if (windowWidth < 992) {
        $(this).find('ul.ul-reset').slideToggle();
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log('PARENT', event);
    }
});
```

Comment: instead of `slideToggle();` use `toggleClass('active');` and add some css for active class.

Comment: Or do you mean: you want the action to occur once the `.slideToggle()` action is completed? In that case you can equip the method with a further argument: `.slideToggle({complete:function(){/* change colour etc.*/}})`

Comment: cars10 can you give like an example ?

Comment: @cars10 it worked!. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CSS class to add the selected css to the clicked item.

```js
$('.navbar-nav li').on("click", function(event) {
  
  // remove previous active_li class
  $(".navbar-nav").find('.active_li').removeClass("active_li");
  
  // add active class to the clicked li
  $(this).addClass("active_li");
  
});
```

```css
.active_li {
  color: red;
}

li:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='navbar-nav ul-reset'>
  <li>Title</li>
  <li>Name</li>
      <ul>
      <li>Title2</li>
      <li>Test2</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: the css is not working, any suggestions through jquery

Comment: The sample I provided using addClass above does not work or your implementation of the above example? Or do you want a jQuery only answer?

Comment: I tried using css but it was distorting the entire view. @cars10 gave the answer though. That works in my case. Thanks anyway